# Oracle limit the number of files of audit

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-11g, audit

I would like to know how to limit the number of files of audit generated in the audit directory, I have an Oracle 12c database. The **AUDIT_TRAIL** parameter is equal to **NONE**, however it continues to generate .aud files, I would like to know how to limit the number of files or if I can prevent them from being generated completely. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Connections ***as sysdba*** or ***as sysoper***, also ***startup*** and ***shutdown*** events are always audited, whether **AUDIT_TRAIL** is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a purge job that you can run to limit the number of days to keep audit records.So you can have the audit records automatically purged. As Eduard Okhvat stated, the default is to audit certain events, whether you configure it or not. You probably want to go through all of the audit events and see which ones are relevant for your organization.

[About Scheduling an Automatic Purge Job](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/audit_admin.htm#GUID-90647C68-F671-4AB0-978F-81D7AB0E63F9)